# How to get exact version of code from a tag (including submodules)

Tags: git, git-tag

I need to reproduce a production issue and need to pull a specific tag. I was able to pull the code via this line:

```
git clone --branch my_abc http://git.abc.net/git/abc.git
```

However, there are submodules to this code base. How do I pull the `my_abc` tagged version of those submodules?

Comment: Does `git fetch --tags` help at all?

Answer (score 1):

Submodules are references to another Git repository, fixed at a certain commit. To initially fetch the submodules after cloning the repository, use

```
git submodule update --init
```

For further updates after that, use

```
git submodule update
```

If you want to update a submodule to its current upstream state, go to the submodule directory and do a `git pull`, followed by a `git add <submodule path>` back in your main repo. This state change can then be committed.